# How Do You Display Sample Code in API-Platform v3

Tags: api-platform.com

I've seen a few examples of code samples being included in Redoc documentation and even tested other openapi.json files within API-Platform document file to prove that it can generate them.

What I cannot figure out is where to put `x-code-samples` inside the openapiContext to generate the Request samples.

[image: ApiResource with openapiContext]

This is what I would like to see in redoc.

[image: codeSample in redoc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is I need to use **x-codeSamples** and not **x-code-samples**

```
#[ApiResource(
    shortName: 'common-data',
    operations: [
        new Get(
            uriTemplate: '/common-data/{id}',
            openapiContext: [
                'summary'       => 'Returns commonly used static data for dropdowns etc',
                'x-codeSamples' => [
                    ['lang' => 'php', 'source' => 'php sample code'],
                ],
            ],
            name: 'common-data_item',
        ),
    ],
)]
```

Then the sample will show up in the redocs.

[image]